# How to Replace primary authentication with custom authentication in ADFS

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs2.0, adfs3.0, adfs4.0

We have a Setup `windows R2 2012 server` with ADFS enabled and able to add MFS successfully, Now I would like to promote this as a Primary authenticator.

I know that from ADFS 2019 we can override the primary authenticator, but how it can be achieved in the older version ?

Is there any other possibilities like integrate ADFS with any SAML provider. If so, where will be the authentication takes place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on 2012. 2016 allows you to add Azure MFA as a primary authenticator and 2019 allows you to add custom authenticators as primary. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/additional-authentication-methods-ad-fs) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/whats-new-active-directory-federation-services-windows-server).